# Is a 1TB drive too big for a boot drive?

Tags: hard-drive, boot

Can the drive you choose to boot off affect performance?  Would I receive faster boot/shutdown times if I were to choose a smaller drive?  How would partitions affect performance/boot speed?  Assuming all drives are the same RPM, lets say 7200.

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/21486/are-smaller-hard-drives-faster

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Can the drive you choose to boot off affect performance?**

- It can affect it, but most likely in a positive way. Larger hard drives can be faster due to higher data density.

**Would I receive faster boot/shutdown times if I were to choose a smaller drive?**

- Doubtful

**How would partitions affect performance/boot speed? Assuming all drives are the same RPM, lets say 7200.**

- Depends on how you partition it, I'd recommend reading [**this great article**](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/setup/expert/tulloch_partition.mspx) by Mitch Tulloch on partitioning drives. He discusses partitioning techniques geared towards performance such as

  - having your page file on a different drive
  - using FAT32 for smaller partitions

Comment: I'd love to read this article by Mitch Tulloch but the link doesn't appear to work and Google doesn't appear to be my friend on this one.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using a Windows OS, it will take ages to defragment the drive.

Fragmentation of the system drive is a crucial factor for performance. So, even if there is a marginal gain due to higher data density, you will lose out on the time you spend defragmenting the drive to keep the drive in good shape.

> Would I receive faster boot/shutdown
>   times if I were to choose a smaller
>   drive?

Most certainly, if you're using a WD Velociraptor as system drive. No 1TB drive is even remotely a match for the performance of a Velociraptor.

Comment: You sit there and watch your defrags?

Comment: i don't, but the time spend on defragmentation has to be taken into consideration and a smaller drive is faster to defragment, as simple as that :)

Comment: Newer windows operating systems do it for you in the background anyway when you aren't using a lot of CPU power so the time isn't that big of a deal. Also velociraptors are 10k rpm drives, he is assuming all are 7200 rpm for the comparison.

Comment: "no 1TB drive is even remotely a match for the performance of a Velociraptor." - http://www.engadget.com/2009/08/03/oczs-1tb-colossus-ssd-gets-a-price-and-launch-timeframe/  ???

Comment: are you implying that background defragmentation does not affect the system performance? and CPU utilazition is the least of the worries.

Comment: yeah, John, give me a SSD any day, preferably RamSan-6200 100 TB, not those crappy OCZs :p

Comment: Defragmentation doesn't affect the performance enough to be significant to your experience. With Windows 7 it uses the CPU power when you don't need it. Not like a traditional defrag on XP where you turn it on and everything is significantly slower.